# Changing HTTP.sys kernel queue limit when using .Net HttpListener?

Tags: c#, httplistener, http.sys

I have an application that uses the `HttpListener` class in .Net 4.0 to service http requests.

Under load I have noticed that I get `503 - QueueFull` - errors reported in the log. A search for this error suggests that it occurs when the maximum number of requests that `http.sys` will queue has been exceeded.

The default queue length is 1000. If you are using `IIS` this seems to be tuneable via the "Queue Length" parameter in Advanced Settings on the Application Pool.

If you are **NOT** using IIS is there any way of tuning this value? Or is the control of this parameter hidden in the HttpListener class and not exposed to developers?

Comment: Have you tried setting the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0\MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU` to something larger? (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx) or any of the registry entries here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris. I haven't had a chance yet to try the settings, however, the blog does suggest that the http.sys kernel queue is different to what MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU is affecting. I had looked at the registry settings for http.sys before and none of the descriptions say they will alter the queue length

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the **HttpListener** doesn't allow to change the **HttpServerQueueLengthProperty** property directly. And [by default this property is set to 1000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364458(v=vs.85).aspx).

But you can try to set it manually after **HttpListener** start. It's hack, because it uses internal property **RequestQueueHandle** of **HttpListener**, so ***use it at your peril***.

Hack:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Network.Utils
{
    public static class HttpApi
    {
        public unsafe static void SetRequestQueueLength(HttpListener listener, long len)
        {
            var listenerType = typeof (HttpListener);
            var requestQueueHandleProperty = listenerType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).First(p => p.Name == "RequestQueueHandle");

            var requestQueueHandle = (CriticalHandle)requestQueueHandleProperty.GetValue(listener);
            var result = HttpSetRequestQueueProperty(requestQueueHandle, HTTP_SERVER_PROPERTY.HttpServerQueueLengthProperty, new IntPtr((void*)&len), (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(len), 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                throw new HttpListenerException((int) result);
            }
        }

        internal enum HTTP_SERVER_PROPERTY
        {
            HttpServerAuthenticationProperty,
            HttpServerLoggingProperty,
            HttpServerQosProperty,
            HttpServerTimeoutsProperty,
            HttpServerQueueLengthProperty,
            HttpServerStateProperty,
            HttpServer503VerbosityProperty,
            HttpServerBindingProperty,
            HttpServerExtendedAuthenticationProperty,
            HttpServerListenEndpointProperty,
            HttpServerChannelBindProperty,
            HttpServerProtectionLevelProperty,
        }

        [DllImport("httpapi.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint HttpSetRequestQueueProperty(
            CriticalHandle requestQueueHandle,
            HTTP_SERVER_PROPERTY serverProperty,
            IntPtr pPropertyInfo,
            uint propertyInfoLength,
            uint reserved,
            IntPtr pReserved);         
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
using (var listener = new HttpListener())
{
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/your/service/");
    listener.Start();

    Network.Utils.HttpApi.SetRequestQueueLength(listener, 5000);

    // ...
}
```

After application start you can check the queue length by running this command:

```
netsh http show servicestate
```

Check "Max requests" property for your process. Now it has to be equal to 5000.